# Add the value of a column to another column on the same ROW

Tags: mysql

[Add the value of one column to another of the same row then update all columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWqOi.png)
I have mysql tbl with

```
column A, B, C, D
value  1  2  3  4
```

I want to add the value of A, B to C and D.
After update it should look like this.

```
column A, B, C, D
value  0  0  6  7
```

Here is the SQL I'm using

```
UPDATE tbl SET 
C =(C+A+B), 
D =(D+A+B),
A = 0,
B = 0
```

Is this safe to use, I'll be updating hundred thousands of rows...

Answer (score 0):

Be safe, lock the table and run it in two queries - first to update C and D with the sum of A and B, then to set A and B to 0 in second query. Always keep a backup before running huge db mutations.